# why my getChildView() is getting called 2 times?

Tags: android, kotlin, expandablelistadapter

my group has 5 items, but it repeat them the same and become 10, i dont know why. below is my adapter and till now any solution for fill_parent or match_parent nothing is working for me.

class FilterAdapter(private val context: Context, private val teamName: ArrayList) :
    BaseExpandableListAdapter() {

```
override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any {
    val productList = teamName[groupPosition].playerName
    return productList[childPosition]
}

override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
    return childPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getChildView(
    groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean,
    view: View?, parent: ViewGroup
): View {
    var view = view


    val detailInfo = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as ChildData
    if (view == null) {
        val infalInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_filter_child, null)
    }
    val childItem = view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.childDetailItem) as TextView
    val linChildLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.linFilterChild) as LinearLayout
    val filterCheckBox = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.filterCheckBox) as CheckBox
    val linCheckbox = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.linCheckbox) as LinearLayout


    childItem.text = detailInfo.name.trim { it <= ' ' }
    Log.e("item", "" + childItem.text)

    linChildLayout.setOnClickListener {
        //                Log.e("filterchildPosition","    "+detailInfo.getName()+" status is now "+filterCheckBox.isChecked());

        if (filterCheckBox.isChecked) {
            filterCheckBox.isChecked = false
            Log.e("filterchildPositionif", "    " + detailInfo.name + " status is now " + filterCheckBox.isChecked)
        } else {
            filterCheckBox.isChecked = true
            Log.e(
                "filterchildPositionelse",
                "    " + detailInfo.name + " status is now " + filterCheckBox.isChecked
            )
        }
    }

    filterCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (filterCheckBox.isChecked) {
            // your code to checked checkbox
            Log.e("filterchildPositionif", "    " + detailInfo.name + " status is now " + filterCheckBox.isChecked)
        } else {
            // your code to  no checked checkbox
            Log.e(
                "filterchildPositionelse",
                "    " + detailInfo.name + " status is now " + filterCheckBox.isChecked
            )
        }
    }

    return view
}

override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {

    val productList = teamName[groupPosition].playerName
    Log.e("listsize",productList.size.toString())
    return productList.size

}

override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Any {
    return teamName[groupPosition]
}

override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
    return teamName.size
}

override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
    return groupPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getGroupView(
    groupPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean, view: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup
): View {
    var view = view

    val headerInfo = getGroup(groupPosition) as GroupData
    if (view == null) {
        val inf = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_filter_group, null)
    }

    val heading = view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.heading) as TextView

    heading.text = headerInfo.name.trim { it <= ' ' }

    return view
}

override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
    return true
}

override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe the problem is not here, please, post the code that use it.

Comment: thanks for response @Augusto here is link of activity code.
https://justpaste.it/7ae2r

Answer (score 0):

what i did is i just decreased the count of getChildrenCount to half it was first half that was repeating.

override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {

```
val productList = teamName[groupPosition].playerName
Log.e("listsize",productList.size.toString())
return productList.size
```

}